# Runtime exception is not serializable

Tags: java, serialization, exception

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path *** threw exception
[javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.] with root cause
```

Above exception thrown in Jax-rs when I am throwing runtime exception.

I have a plain function which throws a runtime exception. I want to map it with exception mapper but for some weird reason above exception got thrown before my runtime exception. Any idea?

Here is the class which has get phone method, with my custom exception:

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException;
import java.lang.StackTraceElement;

import com.server.messit.errorhandling.exceptions.DataNotFoundException;
import com.server.messit.errorhandling.exceptions.IncorrectValueException;
import com.server.messit.errorhandling.handler.ErrorChecker;

/**
 * @author Prasad
 *
 */
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String phone;


    /**
     * @return the phone
     */
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    /**
     * @param phone the phone to set
     */
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        if(!ErrorChecker.isValidPhoneNumber(phone)) {
            throw new DataNotFoundException("Incorrect Phone Number");
        } 
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

Here is the exception class:

```
public class DataNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1422751876879336366L;

    public DataNotFoundException() {
        super();
    }

    public DataNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Here is the exception mapper class:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.server.messit.errorhandling.handler.ErrorMessage;

/**
 * @author Prasad
 *
 */
@Provider
public class DataNotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<DataNotFoundException>{

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(DataNotFoundException exception) {
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(exception.getMessage(), 404, "Doc");
        return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(errorMessage).build();
    }

}
```

Here is the exception thrown:

```
Dec 04, 2018 5:52:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/MessItServer] threw exception [javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.] with root cause
com.server.messit.errorhandling.exceptions.DataNotFoundException: Incorrect Phone Number
    at com.server.messit.core.User.setPhone(User.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.model.SetWithSetter.internalSetValue(SetWithSetter.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.model.SetValueCommand.setValue(SetValueCommand.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.model.ReflectionPropagation.setValue(ReflectionPropagation.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.model.PropertyModel.setValue(PropertyModel.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectDeserializer.lambda$getInstance$0(ObjectDeserializer.java:101)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectDeserializer.getInstance(ObjectDeserializer.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserializeItem(Unmarshaller.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserialize(Unmarshaller.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.deserialize(JsonBinding.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.fromJson(JsonBinding.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jsonb.internal.JsonBindingProvider.readFrom(JsonBindingProvider.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:257)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.gl
```

javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException exception thrown before my exception so I am unable to map my exception to custom json response.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819988/jersey-jerseytest-error-reading-entity-from-input-stream Does this answer your question? Check whether you are using default constructor. The question needs more information about your class as well.

Comment: updated quetion with more data

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I am should not throw exception in my data model class, i.e. 'User'.
So it is giving me serialization error.